# Is it possible to sell your Iphone app from your website, without using the apple app store / itunes

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I am a bit confused and i am hoping that someone could clear things up for me.

1) I want to sell an Iphone or Ipad app on my website. I don't want to sell it on the apple app store / itunes.

I dont want to pay apple 30 present and i dont want my app to be on the itune store.

2) Is it possible to do this?

3) And if so will it only be jailbreak Iphones that will be able to run my app?

4) What if my app was free does it still need to go through the apple / itune store?

The main idea is to sell my own and other peoples apps on my website without the involvement of apple and without them having to jailbreak there phones.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1) not a question
2) No
3) Yes only Jailbreaked iphones
4) Yes

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't unless you jailbreak (option #3), so no, it's not possible through normal means and you won't reach a large target audience with the jailbreak method.

Comment: Yes, and OP will probably produce more profit from using appstore since it's a bigger target audience even though the 30% to apple.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distribute your apps without Apple's App Store. You are right in thinking that Jailbroken iPhones will be able to run your non-Apple approved apps, but in this case you will probably need to sell/distribute your app s through Cydia

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to sell apps through your own website, or even to give free apps away yourself, to customers with stock OS devices.

Apple has iPhone OS security set up so that they get paid their 30%, through their curated App store, and only **if** your app complies with all the rules to be in the App store.

For stock OS iPhones, there are only 2 ways for a developer to distribute apps, through Apple's iTunes App store, and Ad Hoc.  Ad Hoc distribution is for app testing, is limited to a maximum of 99 total devices per developer license (not including the developer's own iPhone), and the provisions that allows the apps to be installed and run needs to be renewed at least once a year (maybe more), or the apps will cease to work, which would make a non-test customer who thought they "purchased" an app quite unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

use html5 to develop app. they come closest to native app and meet your conditions so you do not have to jailbreak device and you can sell them without apple involvement.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The only official way to distribute an app is through the App Store (unless you're using Enterprise distribution).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not yet ready but something like that is in the works -

[Hackers working on Safari-based app installer](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20058917-248.html?part=rss&subj=news&tag=2547-1_3-0-20)

This when becomes a reality enables users to install app from anywhere. That is  the only possibility in near future. But you have to wait ill then.